# JBoss standard output does not show up in Eclipse Console view

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

Using Spring Tool Suite, I recently switched servers to JBoss EAP 6.1.  Now, my standard output does show up in the console.  I've searched for some JBoss configuration changes, but haven't found any yet.

As an example, this does not show up in the Console anymore:
System.out.println("This is a test.");

Is there an easy way to get standard output to show up in the Eclipse Console view when using JBoss?

Comment: I've found the answer for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717329/eclipse-console-not-showing-any-error-log-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your \server\default\deploy\jboss-logging file . You can copy this into it  for example

```
  <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true" target="System.out">
  <error-manager>
     <only-once/>
  </error-manager>

  <level name="DEBUG"/>

  <formatter>


      <pattern-formatter pattern="(%t) %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p  %s%E%n"/> 
  </formatter>
```

Comment: I didn't find this file.

Comment: I also did not find the file, not in EAP 6.1 or 6.4, but there is a jboss-cli-logging.properties under bin. Can you please be more specific. Do we have to create it or something?