# Eclipse console not showing any error/log output

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I am using Eclipse Kepler and i am running Java Web application in **Jboss EAP 6.1** . Today morning i noticed after deploying and running my web application no console output is coming.

But console output showing when i am starting Jboss and its show everything which all application deployed etc. But after that nothing is printing in console .

Can someone please guild me what can be cause i tried plenty of thing mentioned in different -2 question posted in Stackoverflow.

**UPDATE :-**

I tried below code

```
public class test {

  public static void main(String arg[]){
    System.out.println("hariom");
  }
}
```

and its result printing in console but when i am deploying and running web application then only its not showing anything.

Comment: Which logging system are you using ?

Comment: @Berger I am using log4j for logging but everything fine upto yesterday eclipse console showing each and every message/log but suddenly now its not showing anything only showing Jboss log when i am starting jboss

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue will fix with adding following VM argument in your server

Please Go `Eclipse->Server Tab -> Click on Open Launch Configuration ->VM arguments`

And add this argument in VM argument section

```
-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

Here in this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/message/776182#776182) more and detail about the issue

> After reading what has been said in this thread, I'm trying to
>   summarize the use of the per-deployment flag:
>
> 1.0 When per-deployment is true (default):
>
> 1.1 AS7.1.2 is scanning for logging configuration files in your deployment (WAR), If a configuration file is found then that
>   deployment will get its own log context and be configured via the
>   configuration file.
>
> 1.2 Once the properties file is found, it will be read and the application logging will go to wherever it has been specified to log
>   (with the corresponding handler).
>
> 1.3 Logging jars don't need to be included with the application.
>
> 2.0 Setting the flag to false disables this feature, and the deployment scanner will not look for these files. Therefore:
>
> 2.1 You have to use the jboss-deployment-structure.xml to exclude the AS server's logging dependencies you are using and include them into
>   your deployment.
>
> 2.2 Logging functionality is left up to the application. The application should have all the configuration files and required
>   libraries (That's why the server's libraries have to be excluded)
>
> 2.3 If the application had, for example, a log4j.xml but no log4j dependency. The application will stop logging.
>
> Personally, I'm using -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false when
>   I get missing dependencies errors at during deployment so that it
>   displays in the console  the stack trace for the missing class.
>   Otherwise the only error we get in AS7's console (and server.log) is:
>   Services with missing/unavailable dependencies  Which does not make it easy to track down the missing
>   dependency.